# Горизонтальная полоса прокрутки

Tags: html, css

как убрать горизонтальную полосу прокрутки?
http://krovla.pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предыдущем ответе, вам написали.

Но если вы будете использовать `overflow-x: hidden`, а на сайт задет пользователь с монитором в который не помещается ваш контент сайта, то просто лишний кусок сайта будет скрыт. (это нехорошесть!)

Дополню, сайта нужно делать резиновыми, что не было таких ситуаций, что на разных мониторах по разному отображалось.

Или подбирать фиксированную ширину, что бы у многих пользователей не было проблем с отображением.

В своих сайтах если нужно делать фиксированную ширину, то я обычно ставлю 800-900px

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу её, но вообще -

```
overflow-x:  hidden;
```